# Process time changes for each debugging

Tags: time, process, clock

For timing an algorithm (millisecond), I have the below code:

```
clock_t start = clock();
algorithm();
clock_t end = clock();
cout << float(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1000.0 << endl;
```

For each time I debug, the result changes. Could someone tell me why and how I can fix that result?

Comment: Is the variation in the time actually significant? And if so, why?

Answer (score 0):

It is based on current system load. Typically, your OS will be busy with other things and this way, sometimes it will take more or less time.

Actually, execution also is dependent on a lot of other things, like how memory- cpu- and i/o-intensive it is, also again dependent on other things.

I suggest to call algorithm() in a loop, which really is a standard way of getting more repeatable results on a machine, either by a fixed count or actually using the passed time till a certain limit is reached, and then calculating the runtime as the average over the runs.
This will reduce noise and increase precision.